# Format code for a date with time zone in excel

Tags: excel, date-formatting

I have date value with a time zone.

> 24 Nov 2005 GMT+05:30

What is the format code for this custom format in Excel?

I tried `dd MMM yyyy` with `z`,`zz`,`zzz`, and `Z` but Excel ignores those options.

Comment: Is the text "24 Nov 2005 GMT+05:30" actually what is typed in the cell? Or did you just place the date 11/24/2005 into the cell? Problem is once you store it as a date, I don't think Excel knows or cares what time zone it is in. Perhaps put the time zone in another column. Now if your time zone is fixed... that we _might_ be able to do by just putting properly escaped a constant value at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if possible. I've just gone through every letter in custom format cell and nothing looked right.

What I would suggest is maybe splitting it up into a few cells and then bringing them all together.

In the first column (A1) you could have the date, formatted how you like (dd mmm yyyy).

Second (B1) you could have the time before you account for the different timezone (formatted how you like, i.e. hh:mm:ss.

Third (C1) define if the timezone is ahead or behind with a plus/minus sign.

Fourth (D1) you could set the time difference (i.e. your example +5:30). Format the cell as h:mm.

Fifth (E1), enter the formula: =IF(C1="+",B1+D1,IF(C1="-",B1-D1)). Format the cell as hh:mm:ss.

Finally, (F1) there's two options for you. You can combine the date and time adjusted to the timezone, or you can combine the date, original time and include timezone.

The first option would be: =TEXT(A1,"dd mmm yyyy ")&TEXT(E2,"hh:mm:ss")

Second would be: =TEXT(A1,"dd mmm yyyy ")&TEXT(B1,"hh:mm:ss ")&"GMT"&TEXT(C1,"")&TEXT(D1,"h:mm")

This is the absolute best solution I could think of. Sorry if it's not what you asked for.