# How to convert a String date to a Date

Tags: excel, date-conversion

How can I convert this string:

```
Tue Jan 24 14:59:20 BRT 2017.
```

Into a date that includes day month year and time and timezone, using Excel functions only.

I have several cells with dates following this format. I have to compute the difference between some of these dates in minutes. I believe that the first step is converting the date to a String to a real date information. Then, I will be able to: order the dates and compute the time between consecutive dates.

Comment: Excel date/times do not include time zone information.

Comment: ...Doesn't the string already have that? Can you post an example of the expected output? Will all the strings have that exact format? More examples would help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format code for a date with time zone in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610751/format-code-for-a-date-with-time-zone-in-excel)

Comment: How can i break the String and collect the date parts that i need?

Comment: You will need to lose the time zone information, and as such if you are comparing all the date/times over multiple time zones you will also need to convert them to a standard time zone to do the math.  If it is all in the same time zone then this is simpler.  If in various you will need a table that tells excel how much time to add or subtract to get to a standard.

Comment: all dates are from the same timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=--(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,5,LEN(A1)),"BRT",""))
```

Then format it to the format you want.

It will now work in math equations.

[image]

Comment: (@user3444287, If the timezone does change, you could also add a `MID()` to pull out "BRT" instead of putting it in there directly.)

Comment: i was able to remove the timezone using notepad++, but i still cannot convert to a date
https://www.dropbox.com/s/44q0kfxc2ivnqy1/Sem%20t%C3%ADtulo.png?dl=0

Comment: did you try my formula on the original data?

Comment: it not worked, but i think i did otherway using string manipulation
https://www.dropbox.com/s/44q0kfxc2ivnqy1/Sem%20t%C3%ADtulo.png?dl=0