# Formatting existing dates to custom format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z

Tags: excel

Latest Excel, Mac....

I have a spreadsheet with a date/time in this format....

```
d/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM
```

For example: "1/11/2017 10:11:00 PM" (Nov 1, 2017)

I want to convert it to this format....

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z
```

How can I do this? I tried "Format Cells"/"Custom" and then, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z" but it doesn't do anything.

There are 100s of rows. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You may want to take a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610751/format-code-for-a-date-with-time-zone-in-excel

Comment: It's possible that Excel does not recognise the values as dates.  I've had this issue in the past and when you select the cell and press enter it parses and converts to a date.  The solution in the comment above looks like it will work but I've discovered recently that the EDATE() function used for adding or subtracting calendar months will also parse text dates if you use 0. `EDATE(A1,0)` so you can try that and then format the result.